# make all fatal error when caffe is compiled

Tags: python, opencv, caffe

I have installed OpenCV which shows version 3.0.2 when I write python commands. But when I try to run make all for caffe I am getting this output:

```
fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:591: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o] Error 1
```

Anyone who can assist with what the issue I am facing might be here?

Comment: Which version of python did you install opencv with?

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncomment  this line OPENCV_VERSION := 3 in your Makefile.config file.You need to do this if you are installing caffe with opencv version 3